# How to check if a mysql connection is idle in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-connection

I want to close a MySQL connection in Python, but before doing so I want to make sure that the connection is not currently used (idle). How can I check if the connection is idle? We can check if it's closed, but I can't see anywhere to check if it is idle.

UPDATE:

The module is use is `MySQLdb`

Comment: What mysql package do you use (in your python code)? pymysql?

Comment: I've updated the question